How to adjust vertical placement of figure before chapter, chapter heading and section heading in scrbook?
I am trying to create equal vertical spacing in a figure placed at top of page before chapter heading, chapter heading and section heading in scrbook. I tried using the inbuilt koma commands but it is not giving the desired results (or I am not using them correctly. How can I do verical adjustments for the chapter and section headings so that they appear more balanced?

MWE
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}               
\geometry{paperheight=150mm,paperwidth=150mm, textwidth=75mm, textheight=100mm,                 top=20mm, bottom=20mm, marginparwidth=38mm, headsep=8mm, left=10mm, right=55mm, marginparsep=7mm, footskip=10mm}                   

\usepackage{tikz}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=2.75cm]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1cm]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0.1\baselineskip,afterskip=0.25\baselineskip]{section}

\begin{document}




\chapter{first lesson}
\label{ch-01}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.north west)]
\begin{scope}[x={(current page.north east)},y={(current page.south west)}]
\node [overlay,remember picture] at (0.5,0.2) {\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{fig-ch-01-head.pdf}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{first section}


\end{document}


To increase the space above \chapter, you have to increase the beforeskip value of your fist \RedeclareSectioncommand. To decrease the space between the chapter and the section, decrease the afterskip value of the second \RedeclareSectionCommand. BTW: KOMA-Script has a \chapterpreamble command, to add material above (or below) the chapter heading. So you don't need TikZ for this. Note also, that it is recommended to use an image of package mwe for MWE. So we could reproduce the issue without changing anything and also show our suggestions.

Thanks didn't know about the chapterpreamble solved my issues without using tikz. Will use the mwe package, now on.
